# PostgreSQL Syntax error at or near FUNCTION on create trigger

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger

I installed postgresql and postgresql-plpython-10 (using apt) on a new machine running Ubuntu server 18.04
and I have reinstated a Postgresql database (extracted using `pg_dumpall`) from another machine onto a new machine (Linux).

I checked that the trackspreadsheetnztplpy function exists in the database and the table nztgsheet exists. I reran the function on the old machine and it worked perfectly. I checked plpythonu is installed on the new machine using psql command: `\dL`.

SQL error:

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FUNCTION"
LINE 1: ...H ROW WHEN (OLD.* IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.*) EXECUTE FUNCTION t...
                                                             ^

In statement:
`CREATE TRIGGER trackspreadsheetnzt AFTER UPDATE ON nztgsheet FOR EACH ROW WHEN (OLD.* IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.*) EXECUTE FUNCTION trackspreadsheetnztplpy();`

I expected the trigger function to work, but it throws a syntax error instead.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `EXECUTE FUNCTION` syntax for `CREATE TRIGGER` statements was introduced in [Postgres 11](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createtrigger.html).

In [Postgres 10](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-createtrigger.html), you need to say `EXECUTE PROCEDURE` instead.

This syntax was deprecated in Postgres 11 with the introduction of [procedures](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createprocedure.html), which are distinct from functions and cannot be used to implement a trigger.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the old machine was running version 11. Upgraded the new machine to version 11 and now it works!. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add trigger function from pgadmin UI,
In the code tab you need to specify function from BEGIN to END, as postgres implicitly specifies in the code "  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ****()
RETURNS TRIGGER
AS
$$"